# ball thrown inside a freely falling box Centre Of Mass

Tags: classical-mechanics

I had a thought experiment whose outcome I was unable to understand. It involved a freely falling box with a person inside.The person throws a heavy ball at one wall of the box and the ball keeps bouncing between the two opposite walls(completely elastic collision).The first part is that when the centre of mass of the entire system is traced it is a straight line moving down.That was the first part I found surprising.The second part was "what is the motion of the box to an outside observer?".I know the answers to the first part but don't understand it and can't answere the second. Any answeres will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Late comment:  astronomers often use the wiggles in the movement of a bright star (deduced from Doppler shifts) to deduce the presence and properties of a dimmer binary companion star...  Same as ball and box in the OP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the mass of the box. If the mass is low, an outside observer will see the box wiggling back and forth a lot. If the mass is high it will wiggle only  little bit. Just because the outer structure of the system (i.e the box) is seen to move by an outside observer, doesn't mean the system is disobeying the rule about the center of mass that you mention. Note also that the person inside the box will also see it wiggle as the ball bounces.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. Although when the person in the box throws the ball against the wall doesn't it make the box move in a direction opposite to that of the throw? Which means that there is a net motion of the box in that direction?

Comment: If so then how does the centre of mass stay along the same line downward?

Comment: The total momentum of all the objects (the thrower, the ball, and the box) will remain at zero at all times.

Comment: @Digiproc, the horizontal component will remain zero. But the vertical component can change. They're independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the ball is 'heavy' is probably the main reason you're confused. It could actually have any mass you wanted and (ignoring other effects) would still follow the same path.

Why is this?

The newtonian equation of motion for an object under a force is:

$$F=ma$$
Where $m$ and $a$ are the mass and acceleration of the object and $F$ is the force acting on it. Dividing the whole equation by $m$, you will end up with:
$$a=\frac{F}{m}$$
This is interesting, and we'll see why after looking at the force term. 
Forces on objects are the result of the object interacting with a field. The object will have certain charges which will tell us how much it interacts with the field, for example: electric charge $(q)$. The electric field $(E)$ exists without the object being there, and interacts with the object to give us a force $F=qE$
Now, newton's equation of motion gives us an acceleration of the electrically charged object in an electric field to be:
$$a=\frac{q}{m}E$$
So, the interesting thing about gravity is that the charge of an object that interacts with the gravitational field $(G)$ is the mass of the object, which also tells us how much it will accelerate.

The newtonian equation of motion for an object under a gravitational field is then:
$$a=\frac{m}{m}G$$
$$a=G$$
This tells us that no matter what the mass is of an object (as long as $m>0$) it will move the same way under a gravitational field!

Now, back to your original question.

From the point of view of the person in the box throwing the ball, since they are **moving under gravity in the same way as the ball and the box**, we can completely ignore its effect. They are weightless. Now you can just imagine what would happen if you threw a ball on a spaceship, it would bounce backwards and forwards in a straight line.

For the second part of the question, the observer outside the box is being held up against the gravitational field (eg. by the earth), and so they will not experience the same acceleration. They will therefore observe the box accelerating downwards with the ball bouncing inbetween the walls, but also accelerating downwards.

Edit: Just seen that you were instead asking about the centre of mass of the system, and it wasn't a question about gravity. Whoops.

Comment: Thank you! That actually helped me visualise conservative forces better.:)

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the system $S := \{ball + person + box\}$, and let $M_b$ be the mass of the ball and $M$ the mass of the person and the box. The only external force that act on $S$ is gravitation, so with $\textbf{a}$ the acceleration of the center of mass of $S$, the Second Law of Newton says that

$$ M\textbf{a} = M\textbf{g}$$

(Note that the variation of the gravitationnal field are negligeable here, so $\textbf{g} = \textbf{Constant}$). We can say that the trajectory of the center of mass of $S$ will be a parabola.

Now, let's focus on the motion of the ball and the personn and the box. Let $v_{xb}$ be the horizontal speed of the ball in the barycentric frame of reference, $V_0$ its initial velocity and $v_{x}$ the horizontal speed of the box and the person (the person don't move in the box). Since the horizontal momentum of $S$ is conserved ($\textbf{g}$ is vertical) and is null (we are in the barycentric frame of reference), we have

$$ M_b v_{xb} + M v_{x} = 0$$

So $$ v_x = - \frac{M_b}{M} v_{xb}$$

Now, if $M_b << M$, the box's motion will be unnoticeable: it will be as if there was nothing inside it.

Let's focus on the general case. Let $L$ be the width of the box. The energy of the ball is conserved, so the motion has a period of $T:=2L/V_0$. With $x_b$ the abscissa of the ball, and $x$ the one of the box and the person, we then have, with $x_b(t=0)=x(t=0)=0$ and $0 \leqslant t \leqslant T/2$

$$ x_b(2kT+t) = V_0t$$

and $$ x_b((2k+1)T+t) = (\frac{M+M_b}{M}-t)V_0$$

and $$x(2kT+t) = -\frac{M_b}{M}V_0t$$

and $$x((2k+1)T+t) = -(\frac{M+M_b}{M}-t)\frac{M_b}{M}V_0$$

Comment: Thank you I found that very useful for further calculations!